# How to build and install wal2json without also installing the package postgresql-server-dev on Debian 9?

Tags: postgresql, debian, wal

I'm trying to stream data automatically from PostgreSQL 10 to Kafka using debezium together with the logical decoding plugin, wal2json.

I followed all the instructions on how to build and install the plugin from this [link](https://github.com/eulerto/wal2json) by running these command lines:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/eulerto/wal2json.git
$ cd wal2json
$ PATH=/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin:$PATH
$ USE_PGXS=1 make
$ USE_PGXS=1 sudo make install
```

Yet, the steps for installation include this command line: `USE_PGXS=1 make` and it requires the installation of this package

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-10
```

else, I get the following error

```
Makefile:10: /usr/lib/postgresql/11/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk: No such file or directory

make: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/postgresql/11/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk'.  Stop.
```

In fact, I am not allowed to install the package `postgresql-server-dev-10` for personal reasons.

Thus, is there any way to install wal2json without installing that package or without using the command `make`?

Thank you.

Comment: As the are no pre-built binaries available for wal2json you have to compile it yourself. If you can't do that on the target computer, you have to find some other computer with the same OS to build it (e.g. a local VM or something similar)

Comment: Yeah, looks like it's the only way to compile it for now. Anyway, thanks a lot.